# Collect poems from sub links of a web page with Scrapy and put it in a .txt file

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to collect all the poems from under the category "Índice general alfabético" on this site http://amediavoz.com/. There it appears the title of the poems which one has to click to get to the actual poems. Basically I want to copy all the text of each poems from each of these pages (the text within `<p></p>` under xpath "/html/body/blockquote[2]/blockquote" in each of the pages) except the ending information about the poem under `<i></i>` in the HTML code. I would like to save everything in .txt files, either one big one, or one per page.

This code is an attempt to do this.

```
import scrapy

class FirstSpider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = "FirstSpider"

    start_urls = ['http://amediavoz.com/']

    def start_requests(self):
        url = ['http://amediavoz.com/']
        yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):

        xp = "//a[@target='_blank']/@href"
        for url in response.xpath(xp).extract():
            page = response.url.split("/")[-2]
            filename = 'Poems=%s.txt' % page
            sub = url.css('blockquote')[1]
            with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
                f.write(sub.xpath('//font/text()').extract())
            self.log('Saved file %s' % filename)
            f.close()
```

When I run the code I dont get any error message but no output either, that is, a text file.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I don't know Spanish. I just roughly extract the text, not necessarily right. If you can mark which data you need to extract from HTML, I will help you modify the code.

```
from simplified_scrapy.spider import Spider, SimplifiedDoc
class FirstSpider(Spider):
  name = 'FirstSpider'
  start_urls = ['http://amediavoz.com/']
  refresh_urls = True

  def extract(self, url, html, models, modelNames):
    try:
      doc = SimplifiedDoc(html)
      if url['url']==self.start_urls[0]:
        lstA = doc.listA(url=url['url'],start='blockquote',end='La voz de los poetas')
        return [{"Urls":lstA}]

      blockquotes = doc.getElementsByTag('blockquote')
      page = url['url'].split("/")[-1]
      filename = 'data/Poems=%s.txt' % page
      with open(filename, 'w') as f:
        for blockquote in blockquotes:
          f.write(blockquote.getText('\n'))
          f.write('\n')
      print ('Saved file %s' % filename)
      return True
    except Exception as e:
      print ('extract',e)

from simplified_scrapy.simplified_main import SimplifiedMain
SimplifiedMain.startThread(FirstSpider())# start scrapping
```

Comment: This is not exactly what I wanted but atleast it's a step in the right direction. I want to enter each of the links and extract the poems from each of the links and put the actual poems in a .txt file.
Now I am just getting each link in the text file, like so:

{"url": "http://amediavoz.com/abril.htm", "title": "Abril, Juan Carlos", "relativeUrl": "./abril.htm"}

Now I would like to enter each url and extract the poems from each, and save them in a text document.

Comment: I changed the code, I just roughly extract the text, not necessarily right.